# How to upload file in C#?

Tags: file-upload, c#-3.0

I tried this. Will it work?

```
  FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("resume\\"+FileUpload1.FileName + " "));
  StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded;
```

Comment: the above code is right or wrong can any one help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Server.MapPath("data.txt")
```